# How to find larger of two integers using recursion and not using operators in python

Tags: python, recursion

I want to find the larger of two integers. But I have to use Recursion and without python operators.
Code structure is given below.

```
def gt(a, b):
  '''Returns True if a is an integer greater than b;
     returns False otherwise'''
  # using only incr, decr, zero, and recursion
  return 0


def incr(a):
  '''Returns the next integer after a'''
  return a + 1

def zero(a):
  '''Returns True if a is zero'''
  return a == 0

def decr(a):
  '''Returns the integer before a'''
  return a - 1
```

Comment: how about a builtin like `max`?

Comment: Hi Fahim! This looks like a homework question. While we're fine with helping with homework here at SO, we'd love it if you could show what you've already tried. For more information on our homework policy, see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Can you use loops?

Comment: Can we define another function? can we use `-`?

Comment: @mozway no, we can't.

Comment: @user2390182 nope.

Comment: @rv.kvetch thats a built in function

Comment: @FahimFerdous are you sure it should work for negative integers? I have the intuition that it is not feasible with the current restrictions

Comment: @mozway On the other hand,  what do you need `incr` for if there are no negative numbers?

Comment: can we define/use a scalar?

Answer (score 4):

###### version for positive integers

You could decrement both numbers and see whether a or b reaches zero first:

```
def gt(a, b):
    '''Returns True if a is an integer greater than b;
       returns False otherwise'''
    # using only incr, decr, zero, and recursion
    if zero(b) and not zero(a):
        return True
    if zero(a):
        return False
    return gt(decr(a), decr(b))
```

examples:

```
>>> gt(100, 10)
True

>>> gt(10, 10)
False

>>> gt(1, 10)
False
```

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: @user2390182 I thought I read positive integers, let me think

Comment: *"let me think"* :) join the club!

Comment: this would obviously be the same mechanic using incr for two negative numbers, but with two numbers of different sign I feel that there is no direct way

Comment: And you cannot really find out if the numbers are positive or negative without loops, I think.

Comment: @user2390182 I have a way, but this requires to take the opposite (so to use `-`)

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky! I posted one that needs loops...

Comment: Thankyou @mozway

Answer (score 0):

If you are permitted the simplest of loops (using only `zero` for the breaking condition):

```
def gt(a, b):
    # 1. get a to zero by going up and down in parallel
    aup = adown = a
    bup = bdown = b
    while True:
        if zero(aup):
            a, b = aup, bup
            break
        if zero(adown):
            a, b = adown, bdown
            break
        aup, adown = incr(aup), decr(adown)
        bup, bdown = incr(bup), decr(bdown)
    if zero(b):
        return False 
    
    # 2. get b to zero
    bup = bdown = b
    while True:
        if zero(bup):
            return True
        if zero(bdown):
            return False
        bup, bdown = incr(bup), decr(bdown)
```