# Get the greatest of two numbers with a recursive functions (without using any comparison operators)

Tags: c++

How can I just get the greatest number without using (<, >, >=, <=) signs using a recursive function? It must be a recursive function, I searched and found many ways but they wasn't recursive.

Comment: What have you tried (in terms of making an effort to solve the problem by writing some code yourself)?  SO is not a 'please do my homework' service.

Comment: No, I just want a hint how can I do this, not the code, Thought of many ways and no success

Comment: So, `==` and `!=` is not excluded? So, you could decrement one number and check whether it becomes equal to the other. That has of course, the danger of an underflow which is Undefined Behavior. This risk is lower if you decrement both and compare both to the original opposite value. You also could do that with type conversion to unsigned to get rid of the U.B. at all. This could be done in a loop or in a recursive function...

Comment: Near dup (using Python, rather than C++): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828468/how-to-find-larger-of-two-integers-using-recursion-and-not-using-operators-in-py

Comment: Donno about greatest of two,  but there's `std::greater{}(10, 5)`

Comment: Unrelated: Subtraction. If A<B, then A-B will be negative. No need for any magic, including recursion.

Comment: @user4581301 That moves the problem. It seems to me like it is equally hard to know if a value is negative or positive as it is to compare the original values. The usual way of detecting positive and negative values is to compare them with 0.

Comment: Good point, @FrançoisAndrieux and bad explanation on my part. Step 2 is mask the sign bit. For a standard 32 bit 2's compliment number, `if ((A-B) &0x80000000) {return B;} return A;`

Comment: You don’t need operators nor recursion for that, C++ standard libraries have `std::max`

Answer (score 1):

Clearly out of two elements, if the first has the top most bit 0 and the other  has the top most bit 1, the first is smaller (and vice versa).

If the top bits are equal, one needs to shift both values left by 1, then recurse. The `==` operator needs to be applied though for end condition (also when a==b, then we should early exit).

Comment: 'recursion' is a bit overkill, since this is more like tail recursion, or iteration anyway.

Comment: Warning: Watch out for 2s compliment negative numbers.

Comment: Sure, works for unsigned only as is. If signed, then we need to add / toggle the MSB or handle the top bit with inverted logic.